# Application Crashing after attempt to display Comment Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, instagram

I am attempting to display Instagram Comments in a Detail View Controller. I am pushing the data from a Master View Controller shown below:

```
MessageViewController *message = [[MessageViewController alloc] init];
NSInteger row = [[self tableView].indexPathForSelectedRow row];
NSDictionary *pic = [instaPics objectAtIndex:row];
message.instagramData = pic;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:message animated:YES];
```

However when I tap the button to go to the Detail View Controller I get this error:

```
2015-05-02 01:29:56.464 Floadt[40646:4284271] Successfully commented Picture
2015-05-02 01:29:56.516 Floadt[40646:4284271] -[__NSCFArray objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd06be6cc40
2015-05-02 01:29:56.529 Floadt[40646:4284271] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd06be6cc40'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dc5bc65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010d537bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dc630ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dbb913c ___forwarding___ + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dbb8cd8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Floadt                              0x000000010a1104d0 -[MessageViewController messageCellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 256
    6   Floadt                              0x000000010a11035c -[MessageViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 188
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010c36ca28 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 508
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010c34b248 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2853
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010c3618a9 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 210
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010c2eba2b -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 536
    11  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c0afec2 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    12  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c0a46d6 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010c2df675 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 607
    14  Floadt                              0x000000010a0908a8 -[SLKTextViewController viewWillAppear:] + 296
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010c39ffa1 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 487
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010c3c1395 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 887
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010c3cd3bf -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 386
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010c3cdf0e -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 43
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010c518715 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 202
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010c2eba2b -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 536
    21  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c0afec2 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    22  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c0a46d6 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    23  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c0a4546 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    24  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c010886 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
    25  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c011a3a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 462
    26  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c0120eb _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 89
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010db8eca7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010db8ec00 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010db84a33 __CFRunLoopRun + 1123
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010db84366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    31  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010f611a3e GSEventRunModal + 161
    32  UIKit                               0x000000010c26b900 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    33  Floadt                              0x000000010a113c5f main + 111
    34  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010fe26145 start + 1
    35  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
```

Here is my setup code for adding a UITableViewCell to the Table View Controller:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 2;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     return [self messageCellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (MessageTableViewCell *)messageCellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MessageTableViewCell *cell = (MessageTableViewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MessengerCellIdentifier];

    NSDictionary *instaPics = self.instagramData;
    NSString *commentText =  instaPics[@"comments"][@"data"][@"text"];

    Message *message = self.messages[indexPath.row];

    cell.titleLabel.text = message.username;
    cell.bodyLabel.text = commentText;

    if (message.attachment) {
        cell.attachmentView.image = message.attachment;
        cell.attachmentView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
        cell.attachmentView.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    }

    cell.indexPath = indexPath;
    cell.usedForMessage = YES;

    if (cell.needsPlaceholder)
    {
        CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(nativeScale)]) {
            scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].nativeScale;
        }

        CGSize imgSize = CGSizeMake(kAvatarSize*scale, kAvatarSize*scale);

        [LoremIpsum asyncPlaceholderImageWithSize:imgSize
                                       completion:^(UIImage *image) {
                                           UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage scale:scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
                                           cell.thumbnailView.image = thumbnail;
                                           cell.thumbnailView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
                                           cell.thumbnailView.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
                                       }];
    }

    // Cells must inherit the table view's transform
    // This is very important, since the main table view may be inverted
    cell.transform = self.tableView.transform;

    return cell;
}
```

Instagram JSON Data:

```
    {
    attribution = "<null>";
    caption =     {
        "created_time" = 1430594453;
        from =         {
            "full_name" = "Siwani Regmi";
            id = 247899182;
            "profile_picture" = "https://igcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t51.2885-19/10948979_810376228999798_661235337_a.jpg";
            username = "siwani_32";
        };
        id = 976219494210952254;
        text = "perfect night with the most perfect man\Ud83d\Ude1b\Ud83c\Udf89\U2728 #seniorprom";
    };
    comments =     {
        count = 0;
        data =         (
        );
    };
    "created_time" = 1430594453;
    filter = Normal;
    id = "976219491862142549_247899182";
    images =     {
        "low_resolution" =         {
            height = 306;
            url = "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xap1/t51.2885-15/s306x306/e15/11191276_1060001617348197_1550964556_n.jpg";
            width = 306;
        };
        "standard_resolution" =         {
            height = 640;
            url = "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xap1/t51.2885-15/e15/11191276_1060001617348197_1550964556_n.jpg";
            width = 640;
        };
        thumbnail =         {
            height = 150;
            url = "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xap1/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e15/11191276_1060001617348197_1550964556_n.jpg";
            width = 150;
        };
    };
    likes =     {
        count = 17;
        data =         (
                        {
                "full_name" = "Bridget Carroll";
                id = 223765496;
                "profile_picture" = "https://igcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t51.2885-19/11208422_409436919229236_670022667_a.jpg";
                username = "bridget_carroll33";
            },
                        {
                "full_name" = "";
                id = 190249955;
                "profile_picture" = "https://igcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/t51.2885-19/10747956_726218724133062_1939114518_a.jpg";
                username = hayleymarierussell;
            },
                        {
                "full_name" = "Jill Bracaglia";
                id = 205453413;
                "profile_picture" = "https://instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net/profiles/profile_205453413_75sq_1373835555.jpg";
                username = "jilli_beanz";
            },
                        {
                "full_name" = "Priya Nakhre";
                id = 177807366;
                "profile_picture" = "https://igcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xtp1/t51.2885-19/11098479_870674976323434_1264837026_a.jpg";
                username = priyanakhre;
            }
        );
    };
    link = "https://instagram.com/p/2MOnSjQV5V/";
    location =     {
        id = 764529229;
    };
    tags =     (
        seniorprom
    );
    type = image;
    user =     {
        "full_name" = "Siwani Regmi";
        id = 247899182;
        "profile_picture" = "https://igcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t51.2885-19/10948979_810376228999798_661235337_a.jpg";
        username = "siwani_32";
    };
    "user_has_liked" = 0;
    "users_in_photo" =     (
                {
            position =             {
                x = "0.358666667";
                y = "0.32";
            };
            user =             {
                "full_name" = "Sahan Pandey \U26bd";
                id = 435571613;
                "profile_picture" = "https://igcdn-photos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t51.2885-19/10727510_301263856731264_1868575282_a.jpg";
                username = pandeyexpress;
            };
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: The error clearly indicates that you are treating an array like a dictionary. Symbolicate the crash report so you can see the exact line causing the problem. Then you dig into the data and see where you getting an array instead of an expected dictionary.

Comment: Also, try adding an exception breakpoint in your project to see exactly what line of code is making it crash. This will help you understand the problem better.

Comment: @prnk28, just for debugging, tried to push 0 index object and check weather still crash happening.

Comment: @rmaddy I have added Instagram JSON Data to the post. What would be the correct way of accessing the Comments array

Comment: The "data" key gives back an array, not a dictionary. You can't access the "text" key on an array.